# Consider the mapping $Q: M_n(\mathbb R) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb R)$ given by $Q(A) = A^2 + A - I_n$. How to determine $Q$ is smooth?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

Consider the mapping $Q: M_n(\mathbb R) \rightarrow M_n(\mathbb R)$ given by $Q(A) = A^2 + A - I_n$ (Mapping real $n$-dimensional matrices to real $n$-dimensional matrices).

How is it possible given this information to determine that $Q$ is a **smooth** function ?

How can I take the derivative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to. You just need to remember that matrix multiplication is given by writing

$$M=\begin{pmatrix} - & \mathbf{v}_1 & - \\
- & \mathbf{v}_2 & - \\
& \vdots & \\
- & \mathbf{v}_n & -\end{pmatrix},\quad N=\begin{pmatrix} | & | &  & | \\
\mathbf{w}_1 & \mathbf{w}_2 & \ldots & \mathbf{w}_n \\
| & | &  & |\end{pmatrix}$$

Then $MN =(\langle \mathbf{v}_i, \mathbf{w}_j\rangle)$

Since the dot product is a polynomial in the entries of the matrix, it is differentiable. Similarly adding matrices results in a polynomial in all the entries. But then the whole map is a composition of differentiable maps, so the composite also is (chain rule). You take the derivative like you do for all maps between real vector spaces, you look at the partials with respect to all the coordinates, in this case since $A=(a_{ij})$ has coordinates $a_{ij}$, you'd do ${\partial\over\partial a_{ij}}$.

Comment: Should I always think of a matrix as an $m \cdot n$ vector and use what I know from vectors on this matrix ? Why am I allowed to do that ?

Comment: @user111854 I mean, it depends on the context. In this case, it's useful because calculus is done first and foremost on real vector spaces. This means making that identification gives you an immediate road to talking about differentiability, which was relevant for this question.

Answer (score 2):

You don't have to take derivative. Just observe that entries of $Q(A)$ are polynomials of entries of $A$ and polynomial is certainly a smooth function.

Answer (score 1):

Think of $A=(a_{ij})$ as a vector with $n^2$ elements. Then
$$
\frac{dQ}{da_{ij}}=\cdots
$$

Answer (score 1):

Before you speak of smooth function you should establish your manifold first. So $M_n(\mathbb{R})$ becomes a smooth manifold if you identify it with $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$, with the entries being the chart coordinates.

Now $Q$ becomes a function $\mathbb{R}^{n^2}\to\mathbb{R}^{n^2}$ and in fact each coordinate is a polynomial because that's what matrix operations do to the coordinates. And such a functions is definitely smooth. It's derivative is also easy to compute explicitly.